# Error #1064 mysql when creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I tried to find out why this error is keep showing when i create the DB.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>
> ```
>                     'NUMBER(10)            not null,
> email                varchar(50)           not null,'
> ```
>
> at line 4

here is the table that has the error:

```
create table students
(
    name                varchar(30)           not null,
    studentID           NUMBER(10)            not null,
    email               varchar(30)           not null,
    mobile              NUMBER(15)            not null,
    GPA                 DOUBLE                not null,
    courseID            varchar(6)            not null,
    membershipType      varchar               
    groupID             NUMBER
    finalMark           number
    Check (courseID='SWE496' OR courseID = 'SWE497')
    primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `number` type. Try using `int` instead.

Comment: I also don't think it offers `check()`

Comment: @JohnConde It allows it, it just ignores it.

Comment: You're missing some commas.

Comment: so what would the solution be??

Comment: He said what the solution is: use `int` instead of `number`.

Comment: Add a comma after your `membershipType`, `groupId`, `finalMark`, and possibly `check` (?) lines

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few errors here:

1. There is no such thing as NUMBER.  Use NUMERIC or DECIMAL.
2. You are missing commas after the lines for membershipType, groupID, finalMark and Check.
3. membershipType is a varchar, but you didn't specify the length.
4. There is no field called "id", though you are trying to declare it as the primary key

This will work:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    id                  INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    NAME                VARCHAR(30)           NOT NULL,
    studentID           NUMERIC(10)            NOT NULL,
    email               VARCHAR(30)           NOT NULL,
    mobile              DECIMAL(15)            NOT NULL,
    GPA                 DOUBLE                NOT NULL,
    courseID            VARCHAR(6)            NOT NULL,
    membershipType      VARCHAR(10),               
    groupID             DECIMAL,
    finalMark           DECIMAL,
    CHECK (courseID='SWE496' OR courseID = 'SWE497'),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: +1 but you might as well remove the CHECK constraint, because MySQL parses but ignores them. And I'd recommend `GPA NUMERIC(4,2)` instead of `DOUBLE`.